# R pot.ts of multiple graphs and mapping time/date to x-axis from vector

Tags: r

I am using plot.ts function to plot multiple graphs at once based on a dataframe.

The data.frame has in its raw format these 4 columns:

1) date/time string
2) pressure in haP
3) humidity
4) temperature

the one used to plot does not include 1):
I can transform the date string column to a r date successfully. I store it into a vector.

I would like to plot a graph with exactly 2/3/4 and 1) mapped as date/time values to the x-axis.

How can I achive this?
Can I use plot.ts?

Kind regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a zoo object from your data and use the dates as the index of that.

```
> df
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 2
4 4 1
> d <- c('2012', '2013', '2014', '2015')
> z <- zoo(df, order.by = d)
> z
     a b
2012 1 1
2013 2 2
2014 3 2
2015 4 1
> plot(z)     # This uses plot.zoo
```

That puts the dates on the x-axis, with `df[a]` and `df[b]` in 2 subplots.

EDIT: In case you are not familiar with the zoo class: it is basically a time series that can keep dates (or other stuff) for its index.

Comment: Hi Dthal, thanks a lot! It works great! I didn't know something like this exists. However I need more time to understand how to format a zoo object when plotting it. By default the day abrivations show up in the x-axis. Multiple graphs are plotted as well. I really appreciate! af